# How do I close this DIV?

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup

**I had nightmares to close this div using Javascript ..**
My aim is  to get the div popup as soon as a perosn submits a form and X button to close it ..

```
    if(isset($_POST['letter1']))
    {

    echo'<div id="popup">';
    echo' <div class="close">X</div>
    ';
    echo'<img src="images/guytalk.jpg" width="400" height="450">';
    echo'<h2>Hello</h2>';
    echo'&nbsp;';
    echo'<i>';


    switch ($letter1)
    {
   <!--PHP Code -->
       }
    echo'</i>';
    echo'&nbsp';
    echo'How do you do?';
    echo'<div class="loader"></div> <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>';
      echo'</div>';

      }
       else
```

My Javascript so far ..

```
<script>/* event for close the popup */
    $("div.close").hover(
                    function() {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                    },
                    function () {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                    }
                );

    $("div.close").click(function() {
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    });

    $(this).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
            disablePopup();  // function close pop up
        }
    });

        $("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    });

    </script>
```

I would be grateful If you please point out the mistakes . Thanks very much !
I have to submit tomorrow !:P

Comment: Are you asking what your disablePopup function should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that your jQuery calls are all inside the `$(document).ready()` function as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       /* All of your code that references the DOM should go here */
       $("div.close").click(function() {
           alert("clicked!");
       });
    });
</script>
```

If you want to know what the disablePopup function should look like, it could be something like this:

```
$("#popup").hide();
```

But if you already have that function and you are just having an error that you can't identify, then try to follow these steps to pinpoint the error:

First, make sure you are viewing the page with a browser that has a javascript debugger. For example, if you are using Firefox, then get the FireBug extension. It will show you the actual javascript errors if there are any.

Second, if something is not working, you should try to eliminate all other sources of errors, and reduce your code to just the most important parts. For example, comment out your code as follows:

```
<script>/* event for close the popup */
  /*  
  $("div.close").hover(
                function() {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                }
            );
*/
$("div.close").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

/*
$(this).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    }
});

    $("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});
*/
</script>
```

That way, if there are errors in the rest of your code, you can identify where they are. Finally, replace your disablePopup() function with something else like `alert("close button clicked")` just to verify that the click handler is working.

If you do all those steps, you should be able to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Also, you should make sure to put the entire script inside the `$(document).ready()` function. I have updated my answer to suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code inside "ready" event:

```
$(document).ready({
    //$("div.close")....
});
```

goodluck

Comment: Thanks ! I got it .. I used hide function in jquery